# List of first elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list whose elements are (symbol or list) and I would like to replace the inner lists by their first elements. I do this

```
f[list_] := Replace[ list , x_List -> First[x], 1 ]
```

If I test it

```
f[{{a,b},c}]
```

I get expected result

```
{a,c}
```

But I get an error too

```
First::normal: "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[x].
```

Why do I get the error?

---

**edit**: I can alter the definition of `f` such that I do not get the error, but I still do not understand why I got the error in the first place.

version 1:(based on J.M. comment)

```
f[list_] := Replace[list, x_List :> x, 1]
```

version 2:

```
f[list_] := Replace[list, {x_, (_) ...} -> x, 1]
```

Comment: Use `:>` instead of `->`.

Comment: You get this error message when you apply function `First` to element `c` like such `First @ c` since `c` is an atomic element there is nothing to apply `First` to

Comment: @E.Doroskevic But `c` should not match the pattern `x_List` or does it match?

Comment: It doesn't match, yes, but you are using `Rule` instead of `RuleDelayed`. One evaluates its right-hand side at once; the other doesn't.

Comment: @tom you can see more information about it here in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html check `Background & Context`. 2nd paragraph

Comment: @E.Doroskevic It makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f2[l_] := # & @@@ l;
f2[{{a, b}, c}]
```

> {a, c}